# Force open a file

Tags: c#, file, permissions

One C++ program is filling a logfile, it keeps a handle to the logfile. I want to open this logfile with a C# program and parse it to see if a certain line has been added to the logfile.

However, if I open the logfile with C# I get a "this file is being used by another process" IOException. Code used:

```
using(StreamReader reader = File.OpenRead(myFile))//IOException
```

The C++ program opens the file with (I can not change the C++ program):

```
m_hFile = tsopen(m_csFilePath, 
_O_WRONLY|_O_APPEND|_O_TRUNC|_O_CREAT|_O_BINARY,
_SH_DENYWR,
_S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE);
```

Opening the file with notepad works fine so it should be possible to open it. Can I force my C# program to open the file in readonly mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps try opening the file with the `ReadWrite` `FileShare`?

```
File.Open(myFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
```

Comment: Cheers, misunderstood the meaning of the FileShare enum.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a snapshot copy of the log file using `File.Copy` and try to open that.